# AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'load_seek'

Tags: python

I want to append 2 images together in a new image, I can open each image individually and I have successfully appended them to the array, when I try to print `icon.width` or `icon.height` i get the actual width/height from the icon I'm iterating from. My issue is when I try to paste the images, I get this weird error

`AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'load_seek'` I have found nothing helpful so far about this and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```py
from PIL import Image
icons = []
with Image.open('images/poison_copy.png') as copy:
    icons.append(copy)

with Image.open('images/poison_2.jpg') as scopy:
    icons.append(scopy)

# New sheet
first = icons[0]
sheet = Image.new(first.mode, (2*first.width, first.height))
x = 0
for icon in icons:
    sheet.paste(icon, (x, 0))
    x += icon.width
sheet.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
with Image.open('images/poison_copy.png') as copy:
    icons.append(copy)

with Image.open('images/poison_2.jpg') as scopy:
    icons.append(scopy)
```

When you use a `with` in this way, you are telling Python to close the file you're opening when leaving the block under the `with`.  But you are saving away the file handles by pushing them into `icons`.  This means that the two file handles in `icons` are dead...they will have had their `close()` methods called.  The PIL documentation says about the `close()` method:

> This operation will destroy the image core and release its memory. The
> image data will be unusable afterward.

The `paste()` method is failing because you are giving it one of these closed and therefore useless file handles to operate on.

What you want to do is leave the files open until you're done working with those images.  One way to fix this is to replace the `with` blocks with these lines:

```
copy = Image.open('images/poison_copy.png')
icons.append(copy)

scopy = Image.open('images/poison_2.jpg')
icons.append(scopy)
```

Then, close the files right after the paste:

```
for icon in icons:
    sheet.paste(icon, (x, 0))
    icon.close()
    x += icon.width
```